# How can I insert a series into a chart?

Tags: excel, excel-interop

This is in a COM Excel AddIn. Note: this is a more detailed rewrite (after Absinthe's first comment) - with the level of detail I should have started with.

Let's say I have a chart that has 3 line series that use the left and top axis. And 3 bar(column) series that use the right and bottom axis. They each also have some additional formatting that is set on each sub-collection.

Now my AddIn wants to add 1 more line series and 1 more bar series so I now have 4 of each.

I want to keep them grouped - and Absenthe's comment below handles that. But I also want to duplicate existing series [3] and [6] (API is 1-based) for the two new series.

How can I do that?

Comment: Copy each existing series to an array, add your data to another, feed them back in the required order.

Comment: @Absinthe - thank you good suggestion. But it made me realize there's a bit more to it. So I expanded my question. thanks

Comment: When you say duplicate you mean literally copy the series and display it as a new series?

Comment: @Absinthe No I means I have new data for an additional series. But I want the new series properties such as which axis it is tied to, to be duplicated.

Answer (score 0):

I put this query in as a support ticket to Microsoft and the answer I got back was you cannot insert a new series, you can only add a series to the end of the collection.